# Search for a specific field in a csv file

Tags: r, csv

I have gotten from the Datastream plugin the total returns of several 1000 Isin numbers.

My sheet looks like that:

[image]

I want to retrieve for a specific set of ISIN numbers a specific time frame with the prices below this dates.

Currently I am reading the data with:

`data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")`

I tried to access the data via a list element, however that is not possible because the data is not sepearted by columns.

Is it possible in R to do this task for example by searching in a specific row where there is a specific `ISIN` number by a specific date and then take one row below the price?

I really appreciate your answers!

Comment: as Keniajin pointed out, you have to specify what separator used in your .csv file. Try opening the file in excel or calc and saving it anew, choosing your separator. As I can see, your decimal separator is also a comma (probably a German system?) R does not recognize this as a number, so you must replace "," with "." to use the number as a numeric (use `gsub(pattern=as.character("\\,"), replace="\\.", data)`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the data using comma separated as below

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
dta.subset <- subset(data, ISIN="specificISN")
```